# How to read merged excel column in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

[image: Excel file][image: Jupyter code]

Hello I want to read an excel file in python using pandas. Because later I want to add values that file. However I can not read it properly because I have merged columns ,every label consists of 2 column. I searched it but did't find anything usefull.

Comment: all the columns look completely empty

Comment: i know, but the label column is the problem, After "Tarix" column there are two unnamed columns, but they must be "Tarix" this name

Comment: I just tried with an excel document with merged rows but your function is working. It seems to be something about the document. But I'm happy that the awnser works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:/Users/USER1/Desktop/report.xlsx')
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop(labels = df.filter(regex = 'Unnamed').columns, axis = 1)
df
```